# Add a column to a table with a default value equal to the value of an existing column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to add a column to a SQL Server table with a default value that is equal to value of an existing column?

I tried this T-SQL statement:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename 
ADD newcolumn type NOT NULL DEFAULT (oldcolumn)
```

but it's giving an error:

> *The name "oldcolumn" is not permitted in this context. Valid
>   expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some
>   contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.*

Comment: The default value can be a constant, not another column. This needs a trigger, I think.

Comment: ok, how can I do that, I am new to sql.

Comment: Is that always going to be the default, or is this just for populating the column for existing rows whilst the new column is being added to the table?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever just for populating the column for existing rows.

Comment: You have to do it as a separate `UPDATE` then, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD newcolumn type NOT NULL DEFAULT (0)
Go
Update tablename SET newcolumn = oldcolumn Where newcolumn = 0
Go
```

Comment: ..yes, but this will work for the existing rows only. It will not set the [newcolumn] value when new rows are inserted. You need AFTER INSERT trigger etc.

Comment: This adds an possibly unintended default constraint on the table

Comment: @RomainVergnory I agree, it is better to go without a restriction to NOT NULL at first, then populate values with existing column and later add a NOT NULL again

Answer (score 22):

The `AFTER INSERT` trigger approach involves overhead due to the extra `UPDATE` statement. I suggest using an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger, as follows:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tablename_on_insert ON tablename 
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS
INSERT INTO tablename (oldcolumn, newcolumn)
SELECT oldcolumn, ISNULL(newcolumn, oldcolumn)
FROM inserted
```

This does not work though if the `oldcolumn` is an auto-identity column.

Comment: `INSTEAD OF` triggers also don't work when using temporal tables: `SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON`

Comment: The Instead Of Insert trigger is exactly the correct answer unless the column you want to use for the default value is an identity column, as mentioned above, since Instead Of triggers execute before (and are responsible for doing) the table insert and identity columns don't get automatic values until the insert occurs. I know of no other way to make one column default to the value of another column on record insertion if the column is defined as not null with no initial default value.

Answer (score 15):

I don't like them very much but here is how you could do this with an `AFTER INSERT` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TableX_AfterInsert_TRG 
  ON TableX 
AFTER INSERT
AS
  UPDATE TableX AS t
  SET t.newcolumn = t.oldcolumn
  FROM Inserted AS i
  WHERE t.PK = i.PK ;              -- where PK is the PRIMARY KEY of the table
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use computed column to insert new column in a table based on an existing column value

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName ADD NewColumn AS (OldColumn) PERSISTED;
```

OR, if you want to make some changes to the value based on existing column value, use

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName ADD NewColumn AS (OldColumn * 1.5) PERSISTED;
```

Comment: this is the right answer I think, the official answe is only updating one time, the right way is to make it long term and consistent

Comment: Although this doesn't DEFAULT col2 to f(col1), but rather forces it. A proper defaulting behaviour would be if col2 is null, then make it f(col1) otherwise use the val in col2.

Comment: Sure, but that behavior is impossible without triggers and has some really undesirable behaviors and performance characteristics...

Answer (score 7):

To extend [Kapil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1371805/kapil-khandelwal)'s answer, and avoid the unwanted default constraint, try this:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD newcolumn type NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_TMP_TABLENAME_NEWCOLUMN DEFAULT -9999
Go
Update tablename SET newcolumn = oldcolumn
Go
ALTER TABLE tablename DROP CONSTRAINT DF_TMP_TABLENAME_NEWCOLUMN
Go
```

Replace -9999 by 'noData' if your type is varchar, nvarchar, datetime,... or by any compatible data for other types: specific value doesn't matter, it will be wiped by the 2nd instruction.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I want to add a new not null unique column named CODE but I don't know about the value at the creation time. I set the default value for it by get a default value from NewID() then update later.

```
ALTER TABLE [WIDGET] ADD [CODE] CHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR(36), NEWID()), 1, 5))

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WIDGET] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [UQ_WIDGET_CODE] UNIQUE ([CODE])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a computed column, which will even work with `IDENTITY` column values:

```
CREATE TABLE #This
( Id        INT IDENTITY(1,1)
 ,MyName    VARCHAR(10)
 ,FullName  AS (Myname + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Id)) PERSISTED);

INSERT #This VALUES ('Item'),('Item');

SELECT * FROM #This;

DROP TABLE #This;
```

yields the following:

[image: Results as Grid]

Comment: Warning: Computed columns cannot be modified later and they will be updated when source updates

Answer (score -3):

I think it will work if you use `Set Identity_Insert <TableName> OFF` and after the insert Statement that you wrote just use `Set Identity_Insert <TableName> ON`.