# Added a Column to a table and fill it with existing column data from that table

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am updating some code removing a relationship from some terms we have with credit limits. To do this I get to update the database!

The new schema will add a column for CreditLimitCode which will be the same as the old column TermsCodeId without that columns keys. I need to leave TermsCodeId intact for the time being so a rename is not possible.

I attempted the answer for this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249936/add-a-column-to-a-table-with-a-default-value-equal-to-the-value-of-an-existing-c) but that give me syntax errors because CreditLimitCode does not exist and I do not like the default being added.

```
IF COL_LENGTH('CreditApp.dbo.CreditLimit', 'CreditLimitCode') IS NULL
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE CreditApp.dbo.CreditLimit ADD CreditLimitCode VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT (0)

    UPDATE CreditApp.dbo.CreditLimit SET CreditLimitCode = CreditTermsId WHERE CreditLimitCode = 0

    PRINT 'Added CreditLimitCode to CreditLimt'
END
```

I am not sure a trigger for after insert here would be correct because I am altering the table not inserting rows.

Comment: you'll need to use dynamic SQL for this

Comment: @Lamak can you elaborate a bit. My skills with SQL fall into creating tables and some mild updates.

Comment: Is this for mysql or sql-server? They are different products that will likely have different answers.

Comment: good point sql-server that is in the tag though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exec('UPDATE CreditApp.dbo.CreditLimit 
  SET CreditLimitCode = CreditTermsId 
  WHERE CreditLimitCode = 0')
```

because at compilation time CreditLimitCode  does not exist